# Manually passing page number to paginate tag

Tags: pagination

`{% paginate %}` tag takes current subpapage number from url address. Can this behaviour be bypassed and page number be passed directly into `{% paginate %}` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently i needed such thing again and this time i foud out how to do this:

```
{% set query = craft.entries %}

{% set paginator = create('craft\\db\\Paginator', [query, {
    pageSize: 3,
    currentPage: craft.app.request.pageNum,
}]) %}

{% set pageInfo = create('craft\\web\\twig\\variables\\Paginate').create(paginator) %}

{% set pageResults = paginator.getPageResults() %}
```

To manually set result page, you need to pass some number to `currentPage` instead of default value taken from URL. Note that initial query cannot have `limit` param, this needs to be passed as `pageSize` param to paginator class.

Comment: OMG that is so incredibly useful - I am building a Nuxt/Craft app and needed some api calls to paginate. It works perfectly. You are a champion! This should be marked as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to display a set of Elements that *simulate* a paginated query, you might actually be looking for the `offset` Query parameter.

Here's an example of fetching a “page” of results based on a number of `entriesPerPage` and the number of `pagesToSkip`:

```
{% set customPageOfEntries = craft.entries()
    .offset(entriesPerPage * pagesToSkip)
    .limit(entriesPerPage)
    .all() %}
```

Of course, this doesn't include the ability to see how many pages of results you have, or to generate links to other pages of results.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Unfortunetly I cant use this method - i still have to use actual paginate tag, because I need "pageInfo" to create pagination links.

Comment: I think I might need some more context—you can still paginate the normal set of results, separately, and just run this query off to the side (and use information in your `pageInfo` variable: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/tags/paginate.html#the-pageinfo-variable)

Comment: I guess i could do that, but some of `pageInfo` variables would be wrong, for example url of next subpage.